# Getting random "cd: Too many arguments." error messages when using different commands

Tags: command-line, rhel, cd-command, tcsh

I am getting random "cd: Too many arguments." when using different commands, for example `newgrp` or when logging in. Here is a console log showing the issue along with the Linux version and shell type.

```
Last login: Mon Jun  4 10:50:58 2018 from somewhere.com
cd: Too many arguments.
myServerName /home/myUserName>
myServerName /home/myUserName>
myServerName /home/myUserName>
myServerName /home/myUserName>
myServerName /home/myUserName> groups
groupA groupB
myServerName /home/myUserName> newgrp groupB
cd: Too many arguments.
myServerName /home/myUserName> groups
groupB groupA
myServerName /home/myUserName> uname -or
2.6.32-696.13.2.el6.x86_64 GNU/Linux
myServerName /home/myUserName> lsb_release -irc
Distributor ID: RedHatEnterpriseServer
Release:        6.9
Codename:       Santiago
myServerName /home/myUserName> echo $0
tcsh
myServerName /home/myUserName>
```

`newgrp` command actually runs fine, still I would like to get rid of this message.

Unfortunately searching online had no real results as all of them were about `cd` command itself.

I would welcome some help in tracking this issue down.

**Update**

```
myServerName /home/myUserName> grep "cd " ~/.tcshrc ~/.cshrc ~/.login
grep: /home/myUserName/.tcshrc: No such file or directory
myServerName /home/myUserName> grep "cd "  ~/.cshrc ~/.login
myServerName /home/myUserName>
```

---

~/.cshrc ~/.login files:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------                        |# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------G
# Name     : .login                                                                                   |# Name     : .cshrc
# Function : users startup-file for csh and tcsh                                                      |# Function : Users startup-file for csh and tcsh
#                                                                                                     |#
# Note     : Please do not edit this file until you have read the                                     |# Note     : Please do not edit this file until you have read the
#            site policy file for dot-files: /etc/home/README                                         |#            site policy file for dot-files: /etc/home/README.*
#                                                                                                     |#
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------                        |# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
if (-r /etc/home/login && -d /env) then                                                               |if (-r /etc/home/cshrc && -d /env) then
   source /etc/home/login                                                                             |   source /etc/home/cshrc
else                                                                                                  |else
   source .login.old                                                                                  |   source .cshrc.old
endif                                                                                                 |endif
```

Comment: It appears to me that you have a `cd` command in your startup files somewhere. Try: `grep "cd " ~/.tcshrc ~/.cshrc ~/.login`. It may be globally-set somewhere, instead: `grep "cd " /etc/csh.cshrc /etc/csh.login`

Comment: The `gorups` command (and `uname` and `lsb_release`) didn't prompt (so to speak) the `cd` message, so it doesn't seem to me to be prompt-command-related.

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz `tcsh` does not have `export`, but it has `printenv`. It's more likely that there is some weirdness in `~/.tcshrc`, `~/.cshrc` or `~/.login` though.

Comment: @JeffSchaller None of them gave any results.

Comment: @Kusalananda You were right the problem is with the `source` command in the `~/.cshrc` and `~/.login`. I had tried it out manually and found out that the `.cshrc.user` has an alias named `source` (`cd /somedir`) that has overridden the original command. Good example why not copy someone else aliases.

Comment: I will post an answer later on to summarize the comments, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the ~/.cshrc ~/.login scripts:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
# Name     : .login                                                               
# Function : users startup-file for csh and tcsh                                  
#                                                                                 
# Note     : Please do not edit this file until you have read the                 
#            site policy file for dot-files: /etc/home/README                     
#                                                                                 
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
if (-r /etc/home/login && -d /env) then                                           
   source /etc/home/login                                                         
else                                                                              
   source .login.old                                                              
endif
```

The `source` command was overridden by an alias that was a shortcut to some directory. Removing the alias fixed the issue.